# Am I the only one who has a Hebrew keyboard popping up all of a sudden?

Tags: support

A few days ago whenever I'm on hermeneutics.se and go to enter data (question or answer) a Hebrew keyboard pops up with no close button. Is anyone else experiencing this or is it just moi?

Comment: Not here, anyway ... although I am only `n=1`. (It would also help if you detailed the operating system(s) and brower(s) that you're experiencing this with.)

Comment: Well, it is a Chromebook (Chrome OS). I remembered last night that I had visited B-Hebrew to post a question so it was probably something that I picked up from them. I rebooted last night and it went away. Thanks.  http://bhebrew.biblicalhumanities.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1051

Comment: Hi Ruminator - Btw, I think the answer to your BHebrew question is "No", it appears this phrase is at home in Greek usage, rather than Hebrew. See (e.g.) H.A.A. Kennedy's [comments and cross-references](https://archive.org/stream/expositorsgreekt03nico#page/451/mode/1up) in the *Expositor's Greek Testament*. Delitzsch's [translation into Hebrew](https://archive.org/details/hebrewnewtestam00deli/page/367) doesn't use a traditional Hebrew idiom, but merely gives the Greek word-for-word. HTH.

Comment: Thanks @Dɑvïd. The question was approved so I'll look forward to confirmation from that perspective and any new insight they might provide. And it looks like my keyboard issue has been resolved. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have it anymore but I did find this: https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/hebrew.htm

Comment: I don't use Hebrew at all so I'm afraid I can be of no further assistance in this matter but you might be able to get an answer from the b-hebrew forum.

Comment: It looks like this is the same [issue that occurred on Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4785/on-screen-hebrew-keyboard-pops-up-for-no-reason) and [was fixed by Adam Lear](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4787/13438).

Comment: Ah, thanks Alex. It is good to know it won't reappear.